# Passing input from a shell script to another script which uses read

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to speed up some workflow by grouping a bunch of individual scripts we have to just get called in succession by a single shell script.  The problem is one of the scripts I'm trying to call relies on a series of prompts and read statements to get input.

It's a very widely used script so I don't want to go monkeying around changing how it accepts input.  Is there any way to feed it parameters in such a way that it will read them as "responses" to each prompt in the correct order?

Comment: "Don't design your scripts that way" is really the better answer. That said, yes, you can feed input on stdin.

Comment: I wouldn't have had I written it, I can promise that.  Sorry what do you mean, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: *nod*. At minimum, one can check for content being fed in on environment variables and prompt only if they're not set: `[[ $foo ]] || { printf '%s' "Enter value for foo: "; read foo; }` -- which gives you a route to make the script more easily programmably-invoked without changing its behavior for legacy users.

Comment: A special case of this is the `yes` utility: http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes

Answer (score 0):

Simply feed the content you want in on stdin. One easy way is to use a heredoc:

```
./secondscript <<EOF
$first_answer
$second_answer
...etc...
EOF
```

Assuming that the value of `first_answer`, `second_answer`, etc. are all one line each, they'll be fed to corresponding `read` calls inside the script so invoked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.